# The source ~/.profile command throw weird error

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix, profile

I am trying to reload the shell, I googled a lot found this below command to fix it. But when I run the command I am getting this below error `python: can't open file './test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

```
rasminayak@DEBIAN-TEST:~$ source ~/.profile
python: can't open file './test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
rasminayak@DEBIAN-TEST:~$
```

Even I tried

```
rasminayak@DEBIAN-TEST:~$ source .bashrc
python: can't open file './test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
rasminayak@DEBIAN-TEST:~$
```

Comment: Can you share the content of ~/.profile?

Comment: Could you please check what is present on line2 of your .profile? If possible share on your post too

Comment: `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' . ~/.profile` will log each command run with the file it's from and line number, so you can see exactly where the error comes from.

Comment: That said, Stack Overflow is only for questions about *writing software*. Configuring your interactive shell is not an exclusively-software-development-related task.

Comment: Your `.bashrc` is looking for a file `test.py` in the working directory. It's not present there. You should find out why this line was added to your bashrc (& remove it if it aint relevant any longer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove test.py file from .bashrc

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I think one of the allias had `test.py`. I removed it and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @subm, in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and the entry therein regarding questions which "are not about programming as defined in the help center".